# file_put_contents() failed to open stream: Permission denied on CentOS

Tags: linux, laravel, centos

I'm deploying a Laravel app on CentOS. I've following the following steps:

1. Cloned my repo
2. Installed composer
3. Setup config

Now I'm getting the following error message when I open my website:

```
file_put_contents(/var/www/portal/storage/framework/sessions/IDElrNpsn0hu9hjiXAzZRUTHyzm2fqvPHSLy0ZVN): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

On ubuntu I used the following command to resolve the issue:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache
chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

Now on CentOS above 2 commands are not working and I'm getting ErrorException.
Can anyone tell me which command should I run in CentOS 7 to resolve this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. The solutions for centOS is to use apache instead of www-data.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:apache storage
sudo chown -R $USER:apache bootstrap/cache
```

Answer (score 0):

this was the only solution for me!! After 3 days and nothing to do whit permisions, chmod chown... it was the ffffff server!!

semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/bagisto/bootstrap/cache(/.*)?'
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/bagisto/storage(/.*)?'
restorecon -Rv '/var/www/bagisto'

see more here!
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/file-put-contents-2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).